# The @profile decorator from memory_profiler is changing the behavior of the code, specifically of a pandas function

Tags: python, pandas, csv, memory-profiling

I am using the library [memory_profiler](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler) to run some memory profiling and it seems to works fine, except if I use the `@profile` decorator on a function that it's reading a `csv` file with `pandas`. The function works without the decorator but fails to read the csv file with the decorator.

The minimal piece of code to reproduce the error is below, it needs to be in a `.py` file for the library to work properly. It will create a small csv file with the text string producing the failure (only if `@profile` is present, otherwise is read properly). The expected behavior is to print the csv as a DataFrame with the first function call (no profiling) but to fail with the second function call (same function, but profiled).

Is there an explanation for the change in behavior?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#  
import pandas as pd
from memory_profiler import profile

file_path = 'test.csv'
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write('col_1;"weird_col(=CONCATENATE(""    "",G2,"": str = \'"",A2,""\'""))"\n')
    file.write('"bla.""default"",";\n')

def func1(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';')
    return df

@profile
def func2(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';')
    return df

print('No profile:')
df = func1(file_path)
print(df)
print('Worked fine!\n')
print('WITH profile:')
df2 = func2(file_path)
print(df2)
```

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to try the Fil memory profiler (https://pythonspeed.com/fil), which has a non-intrusive mode where you don't need to change code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @ItamarTurner-Trauring. I tried it and the non-intrusiveness is really valuable. The resulting html is a bit strange but it worked great to find some peak in the RAM usage!

Comment: If you can explain what the confusion was, would love to try to improve it, you can file issue at https://github.com/pythonspeed/filprofiler/issues/new